# What are the different ways to convert a generator expression to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, generator

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_gen = (item for item in mylist if item > 3)
new_list = list(my_gen)
```

passing the generator expression to the `list` function is one way I learned to convert the generator expression into a list. Just curious to know if this can be in  any other different way?

Comment: Just use a list comprehension instead of forming a generator and converting it into a list. `my_list = [item for item in mylist if item > 3]`

Comment: wouldn't that come under list comp I was learning gen comp so I was finding ways to change gen to a list but again a list comp is very handy and efficient, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unclear if you're looking for alternatives or just shorter.

For shorter, you don't need an intermediate variable.

`list(item for item in mylist if item > 3)`

Which has the same effect as

`[item for item in mylist if item > 3]`

For alternatives of the generator, you could use `filter` function on `mylist`, but you'd still need `list()` function, or list-compression, or a while loop calling `next()` until the generator is exhausted for alternatives of making a list

Comment: I'm clear with the shorter way I was looking for more alternatives, will try out the next() method, thanks!

Comment: Those two are not "the same". They have the same effect in the end, but aren't the same thing as far as Python is concerned. (For a `list(range(30))`, the `list()`-wrapped genexpr is roughly 44% slower than the list comprehension, too.)

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack the generator:

```
[*my_gen]
>>[4,5]
```

Comment: Does unpacking always return a list?